# Yarn equivalent of npm install -g firebase-tools

Tags: firebase, yarnpkg

What is the yarn equivalent of

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

My firebase tools are v 11.4.2 and I am being suggested to upgrade to 11.16.1.

Answer (score 2):

`yarn global add firebase-tools`

this adds firebase-tools to path "C:\Users[user-name]\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules"